# Third statement in example 2.3.3 in Velleman's How to Prove It.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am self-studying this text to try to finally learn good proof writing and to learn some more abstract math. It's been going fairly well, but I'm stuck on the statement mentioned in the title. Velleman asks the reader to analyze the logical form of the statement $$B \in \left\{\mathscr{P}(A)\mid A \in \mathcal{F}\right\}.$$ This means that $B \in \mathscr{P}(A)$ where $A \in \mathcal{F}$. If $B \in \mathscr{P}(A)$, then $B$ is a subset of $A$. Then, this means the same thing as $\exists A \in \mathcal{F} (B = \mathscr{P} (A))$. This comes from the opening of the section. He says that $$x \in \left\{n^2 \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$ is equivalent to $$\exists n \in \mathbb{N} (x = n^2).$$

This sort of makes sense, but when I think about it harder it becomes confusing. Since $n$ is a natural number, the square of any $n$ will be a perfect square, and thus I don't understand why this statement isn't instead $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} (x = n^2).$ Does this have something to do with the fact that there are an infinitely many natural numbers?

Further, regarding 2.3.3, if $B \subseteq A$, then $B$ is made up of elements of $A$. But the power set of $A$ is made up of sets of elements in $A$. To me this makes this seem like $B$ is two different types of objects and the main source of my confusion. I couldn't find anything on this example beyond the textbook. I see that Velleman is applying the equivalence given in the opening of the section, but I haven't convinced myself that it's true yet. I'm thankful for a nudge in the right direction. I've been going in circles with this one.

Comment: If $B \in \mathscr{P}(A)$, which is *not* the case here, we would conclude that $B \subseteq A$ and no more.

Comment: $B \in \mathscr{P}(A)$ and $B=\mathscr{P}(A)$ are note the same statement, you're confused about that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B \in \{\mathscr{P}(A)\mid A \in \mathcal{F}\}$ means that $\exists A \in \mathcal{F}: B = \mathscr{P}(A)$, so $B$ is a powerset of some element of $\mathcal{F}$.

The set on the right consists of a collection of powersets after all, and $B$ is one one them. Sets (also powersets of sets) can be members of other sets, as in this case.

It's different if we would have said $B \in \bigcup \{\mathscr{P}(A)\mid A \in \mathcal{F}\}$, because then $B \in \mathscr{P}(A)$ for some $A \in \mathcal{F}$ (by the definition of a union!) and then we'd have the equivalent formulation
$\exists A \in \mathcal{F}: B \subseteq A$ instead. But from your remarks Velleman favours my interpretation from the beginning. I cannot check, as I don't own the book myself.

Just as $x \in \{n^2\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$ means that $x$ is the  square of some natural number, so $\exists n \in \Bbb N: (x = n^2)$.
We just say that $x$ must be of the form $n^2$, as the set consists of all squares of naturals, i.e. $\{1,4,9,16,25,\ldots \}$ (maybe $0$ too, if $0 \in \Bbb N$, I don't know what Velleman uses)..

Using "$\forall n\in \Bbb N$" instead wouldn't make sense, as a single number cannot be  the square of more than natural number, all such squares are different.

Comment: Great, the explanation for the statement and the equivalence makes sense now. As your comment also pointed out, I was thinking of $B$ as belonging to a particular power set instead of actually being one. You also cleared up the perfect squares statement, I believe. There's set of perfect squares $x$, and for each one there is some $n$ for which $n^2 = x.$ Thank you.

Comment: @TheFinisher Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

First let's establish that we know what $\{a \mid P(a) \}$ means for some property $P$

$\{a \mid P(a) \}$ is a set, containing everything which satisfies the property $P$

When we write $x \in \{a \mid P(a) \}$ we're effectively saying that $x$ satisfies property $P$, since $x$ is equal to some $a$ satisfying $P$

Building slightly on this notation, we can construct sets like the following one
$\{f(a)\mid P(a)\}$ for a function $f$ and a property $P$

$\{f(a)\mid P(a)\}$ is the set obtained by applying $f$ to every element of $\{a \mid P(a) \}$ and putting everything you get into a set

When we write $x \in \{f(a) \mid P(a) \}$ what this means is that there is some element $a$ satisfying $P$ such that when you apply $f$ to it, the result is $x$

i.e. that $\exists a$ such that $P(a)$ (is true) and $f(a) = x$

---

Note that both of the sets in your examples are of the above form

In the first one, $f$ is $$, and in the second one, $f$ is the function $n \mapsto n^2$ (i.e. the function mapping numbers to their squares)

With this in mind, looking at these two examples

When you write "This means that $B \in (A)$ where $A \in \mathcal{F}$" this is not correct

What we instead have is that $B = (A)$ where $A \in \mathcal{F}$

$B$ has to "match the pattern on the left-hand side of the vertical bar" in order for it to belong to the set, which means it must be *equal to* $(A)$ for some $A$, not be an element of it.

I think part of the confusion here comes from the fact that this set $\{(A) \mid A \in \mathcal{F} \}$ is a set, whose elements are themselves sets of sets. Just remember that this $\{f(a) \mid P(a) \}$ notation doesn't care whether $f(a)$ is a set, a set of sets, or anything else. It treats it as a "pattern to match with" in the same way irrespective of how much internal structure it has.

---

For the second example, $x$ again has to "match the pattern", so it has to be the square of a natural number

The "for all" statement that you wrote $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \: (x = n^2)$ is asserting that $x$ is (simultaneously) the square of every single natural number

This is a much stronger condition than what we require (so strong that it's impossible to fulfill)

Instead we want that $x$ is the square of *some* natural number (that's enough to match the pattern and establish that it belongs to the set), so we only need $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} \: (x = n^2)$

If we wanted to write that "the square of every natural number is itself a square", then we'd instead write this as $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \: \exists m \in \mathbb{N} \: (m = n^2)$

This is true, but not relevant to what's going on in this example. All that's being said is that $x$ belongs to the set of all square numbers, which is the same as saying that $x$ is a square number. Nothing more.